# How to set the extent with gdal_rasterize, the "-te" does not work

Tags: python, gdal

I am using gdal_rasterize to clip mask by shapefile. However, the parameter "-te" does not work.

I use subprocess to call GDAL util:

```
import subprocess

# define paths to raster and vector
inraster = r'I:\HY_project\HY1B-JPG2\2011\deepwater\test\H1B_OPER_OCT_L1A_20110120T_011319707_geo.img'
inshape = r'I:\HY_project\HY1B-JPG2\2011\deepwater\test\H1B_OPER_OCT_L1A_20110120T_011319707_geo.shp'

# the extent of shapefile
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dataSource = driver.Open(shp, 0)
layer = dataSource.GetLayer()
feature = layer[0]
geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
extent = geom.GetEnvelope()
xmin = extent[0]
xmax = extent[1]
ymin = extent[2]
ymax = extent[3]

cmd = 'gdal_rasterize -burn -999 -te '+str(xmin)[0:7]+' '+str(ymin)[0:7]+' '+str(xmax)[0:7]+' '+\
     str(ymax)[0:7]+' '+inshape + ' ' + inraster

cmd = 'gdal_rasterize -burn -999 -i -te 130.827 24.8857 140.357 26.8057 '+ inshape + ' ' + inraster

# run command
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

If the parameter "-te" is not set then the following command line works:

```
cmd = 'gdal_rasterize -burn -999 -i '+ inshape + ' ' + inraster
```

Comment: what does gdalinfo say for the image? may be projection is different or lat/lon not lon/lat

Comment: Does image H1B_OPER_OCT_L1A_20110120T_011319707_geo.img already exist? What do you mean with "parameter -te does not work"? In which way it does not work?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a temporary layer and use gdal.RasterizeLayer toburn a value to the raster. Create a masked array to set the nodata value.

```
    geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    name = feature.GetField("name")
    env = geom.GetEnvelope()
    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = env[0], env[2], env[1], env[3]

    minX = round(min_x / cellsize, 0) * cellsize
    maxX = round(max_x / cellsize, 0) * cellsize 
    minY = round(min_y / cellsize, 0) * cellsize
    maxY = round(max_y / cellsize) * cellsize 

    ncol = int((maxX - minX) / cellsize)
    nrow= int((maxY - minY) / cellsize)

    tmp_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', ncol, nrow, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    tmp_ds.SetGeoTransform((
        minX, cellsize, 0,
        maxY, 0, -cellsize,
    ))

    #  Create for target raster the same projection as for the value raster
    dsmem = driver.CreateDataSource("/vsimem/temporarely.shp")
    l_out_mem = dsmem.CreateLayer("memlayer", srs, ogr.wkbPolygon)
    # Add an ID field
    idField = ogr.FieldDefn("id", ogr.OFTInteger)
    l_out_mem.CreateField(idField)

    # Create the feature and set values
    featureDefn = l_out_mem.GetLayerDefn()
    out_feature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
    out_feature.SetField("id", 1)
    out_feature.SetGeometry(geom.Clone())
    l_out_mem.CreateFeature(out_feature)

    # burn value 1 to new raster    
    tmp_ds.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(tmp_ds, [1], l_out_mem, burn_values=[1])

    dsmem = None
    # clip same extent from srcImage
    cellX = int((minX - xOrigin) / pixelWidth)
    cellY = int((yOrigin - maxY) / -pixelHeight)

    nparr = rb.ReadAsArray(cellX, cellY, ncol, nrow)


    # create mask from rasterized layer
    bandmask = tmp_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    datamask = bandmask.ReadAsArray(0, 0, ncol, nrow).astype(np.float)
    datamask[datamask == 0] = 'nan'

    # Mask zone of raster
    if (nparr is not None):
        zonedata = nparr * datamask
        zonedata[zonedata == src_ds_nd] = 'nan'
        n = np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(zonedata))

    if (nparr is None or n < 1) :
        QMessageBox.information(None, "No data is found in feature: "+name,"")
        continue

    # set NoData as nan
    zonedata = zonedata.astype(np.float)
    zonedata[zonedata == src_ds_nd] = 'nan'

    # write the clipped raster to file   
    target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(os.path.join(OUT_FOLDER, name+'.tif'), nkol, nrij, 1, gdal_datatype)
    target_ds.SetGeoTransform((minX, cellsize, 0, maxY, 0, -cellsize, ))

    # Create for target raster the same projection as for the value raster
    target_ds.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())
    outBand = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

    # write the data
    outBand.WriteArray(zonedata, 0, 0)
    outBand.FlushCache()
    outBand.SetNoDataValue(-9999)
    target_ds = None
    outBand = None
```